# Extension of the stochastic integral in the book "PDE and Martingale Methods in Option Pricing"

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, stopping-times

In [chapter 4.4](https://books.google.de/books?id=g0LlXe5iN3AC&pg=PA160&lpg=PA160&dq=%22Now+we+define+the+stochastic+integral%22+%2B+%22step+by+step%22&source=bl&ots=R_3r07egB5&sig=7G6vG4Oqb1rDBkOmNzwfog-kjB8&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwizi_Wuw_bPAhUBWiwKHd_mCnIQ6AEIHjAA) the authors of *PDE and Martingale Methods in Option Pricing* do the following: They take a filtered proabability space $(\Omega,\mathcal A,(\mathcal F_t)_{t\in[0,\:T]},\operatorname P)$ and an $\mathcal F$-progressively measurable $u:\Omega\times[0,T]\to\mathbb R$ with $\operatorname P\left[u\in\mathcal L^2\left(\left.\lambda^1\right|_{[0,\:T]}\right)\right]=1$ (where $\lambda^1$ denotes the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R$) and define $$A_t(\omega):=\begin{cases}\displaystyle\int_0^tu(\omega)^2\:{\rm d}\lambda^1&\text{, if }u(\omega)\in\mathcal L^2\left(\left.\lambda^1\right|_{[0,\:T]}\right)\\0&\text{, otherwise}\end{cases}\;\;\;\text{for }(\omega,t)\in\Omega\times[0,T]\;.$$ We can show that $A$ is an $\mathcal F$-adapted continuous stochastic process on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$. Now, [they define](https://books.google.de/books?id=g0LlXe5iN3AC&pg=PA160&lpg=PA160&dq=%22Now+we+define+the+stochastic+integral%22+%2B+%22step+by+step%22&source=bl&ots=R_3r07egB5&sig=7G6vG4Oqb1rDBkOmNzwfog-kjB8&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwizi_Wuw_bPAhUBWiwKHd_mCnIQ6AEIHjAA) $$\tau_n:=\inf\left\{t\in[0,T]:A_t\ge n\right\}\wedge T$$ for $n\in\mathbb N$ and [state that](https://books.google.de/books?id=g0LlXe5iN3AC&pg=PA160&lpg=PA160&dq=%22Now+we+define+the+stochastic+integral%22+%2B+%22step+by+step%22&source=bl&ots=R_3r07egB5&sig=7G6vG4Oqb1rDBkOmNzwfog-kjB8&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwizi_Wuw_bPAhUBWiwKHd_mCnIQ6AEIHjAA) $$\operatorname P\left[\tau_n\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}T\right]=1\tag 1$$ and $$\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}F_n=\Omega\setminus N\tag 2$$ for some $\operatorname P$-null set $N$ and $$F_n:=\left\{\tau_n=T\right\}=\left\{A_T\le n\right\}\;.\tag 3$$

> I've got vaarious problems with $(1)$, $(2)$ and $(3)$:
>
> 1. It's clear that each $\tau_n$ is an $\mathcal F$-stopping time with $\tau_n\le\tau_{n+1}$. However, isn't it obvious that $$\tau_n\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}T\tag{3'}$$ holds surely? Why do they state that $(3')$ only holds with probability $1$?
> 2. Isn't the equality in $(3)$ wrong? It's clear that $t\mapsto A_t$ is increasing. Let $$\tau_n':=\inf\left\{t\in[0,T]:A_t>n\right\}\;.$$ Then, $$\left\{A_T\le n\right\}\subseteq\left\{\tau_n'=T\right\}\;,$$ but the other inclusion doesn't seem to hold. So, what's really correct?
> 3. What is $N$ exactly? I guess $N=\left\{\Phi\not\in\mathcal L^2\left(\left.\lambda^1\right|_{[0,\:T]}\right)\right\}$, but that doesn't make sense (for the same reason why $(1)$ doesn't make sense). On the one hand, the author set $A=0$ on this $N$. On the other hand, he acts as he hadn't done this.

Answer (score 1):

**This is an answer to 2.**

Let $\omega\in\left\{\tau_n=T\right\}$. Either $A_T(\omega)\ge n$ or $A_T(\omega)<n$. In the second case, we're done. In the first case, $$A_t(\omega)<n\;\;\;\text{for all }t\in[0,T)\tag 4$$ (by definition of $\tau_n(\omega)=T$) and since $A$ is continuous, we obtain $$A_T(\omega)=\lim_{t\to T-}A_t(\omega)\le n\tag 5\;.$$ Thus, $$A_T(\omega)=n\;.\tag 6$$ So, we can conclude that $$\left\{\tau_n=T\right\}=\left\{A_T=n\right\}\cup\left\{A_T<n\right\}=\left\{A_T\le n\right\}\;.\tag 7$$

Answer (score 0):

1. You are correct.
2. $\cup_n F_n=\{A_T<\infty\}$, but the hypotheses do not imply that $\operatorname P[A_T<\infty]=1$. **Example:** $T=1$ and $u(\omega,s)=(1-s)^{-1/2}$ for all $\omega$ and $0\le s<1$. Then $A_t(\omega)<\infty$ for all $\omega$ and $t\in[0,1)$, $\tau_n(\omega)=1-e^{-n}$, and $\cup_nF_n =\emptyset$.
   (Or is there a typo in your statement of the matter, so that we should be assuming $s\mapsto u(\omega,s)\in \mathcal L^2(\lambda|_{[0,T]})$ for a.e. $\omega$?)

Comment: I've noticed that I've mistakenly written "$A_t(\omega)=\int_0^tu(\omega)^2$, if $u(\omega)\in\mathcal L^2\left(\left.\lambda^1\right|_{[0,\:\color{red}{t}]}\right)$". I've intended to write "if $u(\omega)\in\mathcal L^2\left(\left.\lambda^1\right|_{[0,\:\color{red}{T}]}\right)$". Then you should agree to me that $A_T<\infty$ surely.